# dead-tree periodicals on Mac development?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

upon being asked about subscribing to hardcopy periodicals concerning Macintosh development, I could only think of 'MacTech'.

are there any others? (and are they any good?)

thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any others, but then I do tend to read Mac developer articles online, if at all. Even more than that, the relatively niche potential readership is probably the biggest reason why there aren't more Mac technical magazines.

I've considered subscribing to MacTech again (I did briefly about 10 years back) but find I rarely end up reading magazines enough to justify the cost. Long-term, it's much more economical to buy the [MacTech archives DVD](http://www.mactech.com/dvd/), although it's not hardcopy and you don't get the most recent content. I sure wish MacTech.com had a model that allowed readers to subscribe to content online and not receive the physical magazine.

Comment: As an update, MacTech Magazine is also available on iPad. See http://www.mactech.com/iPad for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any printed periodicals other than MacTech.  I've filled that gap with a few other forms of electronic media.  I know you were looking for printed material, but I'll pass on a few of my methods of information satiation as a Mac dev.

First, on the book front, nothing is better than [O'Reilly's Safari](http://safaribooksonline.com) online book subscription.  From here, you can stay on top of all the latest general development, Mac development, and iPhone development books.  My favorite for Mac development is definitely Cocoa® Programming for Mac® OS X, Third Edition by Aaron Hillegass.

Second, for relatively static reference sites, you of course have [Apple's development site](http://developer.apple.com) - but another good user sponsored reference site is [CoocaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/).

Third, for more dynamic and real-time information, you have to follow a number of blogs from Apple employees and indie software developers.  There are countless great blogs out there, but a few of my favorites (and active) to get you started:

- [NSBlog](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/) by Mike Ash
- [BBum's Weblog-o-mat](http://www.friday.com/bbum/) by Bill
  Bumgarner
- [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com) by Matt
  Gallagher

Then, for the most interactive experience, irc is the place to get quick answers and to often lurk for some interesting information (and help others of course) - go to irc.freenode.net - the following rooms are relevant:

- ## macdev
- ## macosxdev
- ## cocoadev
- ## objc
- ## cocoa
- ## iphonedev

Lots of great information is available for the Mac developer!